# Starting to write a formal letter, "Monsieur" or "M."?

Tags: correspondance

Should I write "Monsieur" or "M." to start writting a formal letter?
And to finish it, is it okay to say "Restant à votre entière disposition, pour tout ce que vous voudriez."?

Comment: *... pour tout ce que vous voudriez* est dangereux : vous vous mettez éventuellement en position d'esclave (sexuel)

Comment: You should ask this as two different questions since answers to the two questions are not related to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pour le courrier officiel toujours s'adresser à *Monsieur* (ou *Madame*).

L'abréviation *M.* (ou *Mme*) peut être utilisée si l'on nomme des personnes que le correspond connaît :
M.DUPONT responsable du secteur... Mme DURANT directrice de... Me JEAN avocat d'affaire...

> Je reste à votre disposition pour vous fournir tout renseignement que vous jugeriez utile de me demander.

est une formule de politesse qui peut convenir dans beaucoup de situations.

P.S. : [*Liste des abréviations*](http://les-abreviations.com/civilite.html)

Answer (score 2):

Je reste à votre entière disposition.... On préférera une phrase construite avec un sujet et un verbe plutôt qu'un participe présent.

Et surtout en fin de courrier il existe des formules de politesse que l'on place après.

Veuillez agréer, Madame, l'expression de mes salutations distinguées.
Veuillez agréer, Monsieur, l'expression de mes sentiments les meilleurs.

Il y en a d'autres, très codifiées.

Et on laisse son nom et on signe.

Answer (score 1):

On écrit en début de courrier officiel "Madame, Monsieur," si on ne connaît pas le genre de la personne.